# Cancel Terminal Password

Tags: terminal

When say using sudo, it requires a password. But at the instance, I decide that I do not actually want to take the command (or forget the password and want to try again later). What should I do other than close the terminal externally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type <kbd>Control-c</kbd> to kill the command.

Comment: I probably did something else that did not make it work.